# Using New Relic with a modx website

Tags: modx, newrelic, modx-revolution

I just installed new relic on my server and see that they do not support modx cms as a php framework by default.

Has anyone used this tool with a modx site previously? Looking for some direction on getting it configured so that it returns more than /index.php using their api but their documentation is not overly clear for new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the New Relic PHP agent lets you integrate most unsupported frameworks by using   `newrelic_name_transaction()`. There's a separate [guide](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/features/php-frameworks-integrating-support-new-relic) explaining how to use this API call for reporting better transaction names.